# Meaning of the name Sivan

Tags: names, calendar

I recently met a young lady with the name of Sivan. She did not know the meaning of it, other than it is a name of a month. I was wondering if there is a meaning to this name and what it is?

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9F), it derives from the Babylonian word for "set time," or from the Assyrian word meaning [apparently] "heat of the sun." But the name in use nowadays is certainly just taken from the month, much like "June" in English.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [baby naming website](http://www.birthvillage.com/Name/Sivan), the name comes from a Biblical word meaning "bush or thorn"

Comment: I don't want to sound too negative, but sites like those are notoriously (in my mind) blatant fabricators or perpetuators of misinformation and misetymology. Which is not to say "bush or thorn" is wrong, just that the corroboration doesn't help the case for me.

Comment: What Hebrew word would that be?

Comment: Sounds like pure baloney to me. Apparently they aren't even aware that it's the name of a month. Why would someone name their kid "bush or thorn," anyway?

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it's the historically true meaning. That website is popular for people to pick baby names.  It's a possible meaning that the parents might have in mind.

Comment: @Dave, re "Why would someone name their kid 'bush or thorn,' anyway?", consider _Hadasa_ and _Shoshana_, about both of which a Web page may well say "means 'bush'".

Comment: Checked for the word Sivan in Tanach, Talmud Bavli and Zohar. It appears only as a month.

Comment: @msh210, maybe they're assuming (probably erroneously) it's related to סְּבַךְ, as in [Gen. 22:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0122.htm#13).